# Nuxtjs buttom DropDown

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dropdown

I'm building a buttom like Dropdown, this button is for print and dowloand document, so this is my code:

```
<template>
            <v-menu
              transition="slide-y-transition"
              bottom 
              offset-y
            >
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" >
                <v-btn
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on"
                >
                  Actions
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(item, index) in actions"
                  :key="index"
                  @click="item.to" 
                >
                  <v-list-item-title class="white--text">
                    {{item.title}}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
</template>

<script>

export default {

    data()=>({
    actions: [
      {
        title: 'Print',
        to: 'print()'
      },
      {
        title: 'Download',
        to: 'download()'
      }       
    ]
    }),

    methods: {
      print() {
       //some code    
      },
      download() {
       //some code    
      }
    }

</script>
```

so, when a try to click in button and select opction "Print" this error is showing me:

```
TypeError: handler.apply is not a function
```

why this error is showing me??

is possible call one function like string??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the method names without `()` then add a handler method for the click event as follows :

```
 @click="handleMethod(item.to)"
```

and in script :

```
export default {

    data()=>({
    actions: [
      {
        title: 'Print',
        to: 'print'
      },
      {
        title: 'Download',
        to: 'download'
      }       
    ]
    }),

    methods: {
      print() {
       //some code    
      },
      download() {
       //some code    
      },
     handleMethod(method){
       this[method]()
      }
    }
}
```

or just remove the `()` from the method names and try out `@click="this[item.to]()"`

Comment: thanks!!!! I do it using handleMethod(method) and work... I tried with @click="this[item.to]()" but, don't work, when I selected option "Print" work but whe I selected option"Donwload" this error is showing download is not definite

Comment: are you sure that you didn't make a mistake in the method name?

Comment: yes I do.... this is the error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'download' of null"

Comment: I think the error is inside the method itself